# how to clean the obs values in a column in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the following data:

```
head(MS.data.in)
  encounter_id patient_nbr            race gender     age weight admission_type_id
1      2278392     8222157       Caucasian Female  [0-10)      ?                 6
2       149190    55629189       Caucasian Female [10-20)      ?                 1
3        64410    86047875 AfricanAmerican Female [20-30)      ?                 1
4       500364    82442376       Caucasian   Male [30-40)      ?                 1
5        16680    42519267       Caucasian   Male [40-50)      ?                 1
6        35754    82637451       Caucasian   Male [50-60)      ?                 2
```

I wud like to change the obs of 'age' column by taking the upper 2 digits of the given interval something as shown below:

```
head(MS.data.in$age)
[1] 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the values by matching characters until the `-` (`.*-`) followed by numbers inside a capture group (`(\\d+)`) followed by characters until the end of string (`.*`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group.

```
MS.data.in$age <- as.numeric(sub(".*-(\\d+).*", "\\1", MS.data.in$age))
MS.data.in$age
#[1] 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

Comment: excellent..it will take time for me to understand how `sub' works.....was trying for the first two digit of the interval by modifyng the code..failed miserably!